# ArcScene Extrusion Is not proportioned correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, 3d-analyst, arcscene, extrude

I am new to ArcScene so I have no idea what I am doing.

In ArcGIS Desktop I have a buildings layer that I would like to make into 3D.

I created a field in ArcGIS Desktop with the building heights and used that field as the Extrusion value.

When I press apply the building are like really high and obviously not correct. I tried doing /10, /100, and even /1000, but then building either were still too high or were 2D again.

I do not know what to do at this point. I am using GCS_WGS_1984 as my coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably due to GCS_WGS_1984 unit being degree, I guess ArcScene is reading your building heights as degree and not meter.

A solution would be to use a projected coordinate system (could work in data view with on the fly reprojection, if not you have to reproject your data)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to re-project my data using the Define Projection tool, but for some reason when I try to reproject it with a projected coordinate system, my data disappears.

Comment: Oh nevermind! I figured it out. I needed to change the Scene Layer Coordinate System for the whole map. It is working now.

Comment: In that case I suggest to accept the answer. Nevermind is not a good way to say thank you.

Comment: Define Projection tool do not reproject your data it simply change the coordinate system associated with it. To reproject you need to use the project tool